# Deploying Node.js app with gdal | AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gdal

I'm trying to deploy a node.js app but get stuck with an error about missing dependencies for [gdal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdal).

`Error: /lib64/libm.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /var/app/current/node_modules/gdal/lib/binding/gdal.node)`

How would I go about installing this required dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gdal-async` on npm explicitly supports AWS.

As its author, I will be happy to help you if it doesn't work - you can create an issue on github.

I don't know what you call `gdal.js`.

There is the original `gdal` by Mapbox and Natural Atlas that is not actively developed anymore.

There is `gdal-next` on which I used to work a little bit which has a current version of GDAL but it is not very active either.

There is my `gdal-async` which is the only one that is currently active.

And there is an Emscripten port that is pure JS and runs in the browser, but it is stalled at GDAL 2.

Supporting AWS is simply a matter of compiling with the right libraries.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and with no code rewrite other than the include. Great job! The module I used before was the one simply called  [gdal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdal).

Comment: `gdal-async` builds upon `gdal` - which is not really maintained anymore